# useEffect should call even the props is have same value also

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If the props get changed only the useeffect() is calling because i'm passing value as a second argument. But if the props get the same value also i need to call the useEffect to tab changes functionalities.That means whenever the coMponent is call i need to call the useeffeect.

Parent Component :

```
<Tabs selectedTabIndex={data.isevaluation === "true" ? 2 : tabIndex !== -1 ? tabIndex : 0
    } onTabChange={handleTabChangeOrValidateTheme}>
```

Child Coponent:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   if (selectedIndex !== selectedTabIndex) {
      setSelectedIndex(selectedTabIndex);
   }
}, [selectedTabIndex, elementId]);
```

If i remove the 2 argument its calling each setstate.But i need to call only the component call that means only the props get new value or same value. Please anyone help im new to hooks.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(selectedTabIndex)

React.useEffect(() => {
   // will run when selectedTabIndex changes
   setSelectedIndex(selectedTabIndex);
}, [selectedTabIndex]);
```

this should be enough

Comment: I need to call if the selectedTabIndex value is same also.For that if i remove the 2nd argument in the sense setStateIndex function is calling continuously.Whenever the component is call at the time i need to call useEffect even if the prop is same

Comment: useEffect should call even the props has the same value